# I am a beginner in jQuery, please help me to understand this code

Tags: jquery

what does this function do?

```
 function topRise() {
        $(".topRise").animate({
            top: "-900px"
        }, 25000, topSet);
 };
```

Comment: It finds the element on the page with the class of "topRise" and then fires the animate function on it. Moving it 900px up the page.

Answer (score 8):

When you call `topRise()` anywhere in `js` it will `animate`/`move` the element/s with class named `topRise` and the movement will happen to `-900px` to `top` and this will happen within a span of 25000 milliseconds i.e. **25 seconds**. the callback `topSet` is a function that gets executed once 25 seconds of animation gets completed

Comment: It appears everyone has "sort by votes" and not "oldest" turned on today. Enjoy :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie.. Feeling is mutual bro.. :D But I've sorted according to **Active** ;)

Comment: By **Active**... Which puts us both right at the bottom... :P

Comment: Lol yea.. @TrueBlueAussie .. :D I was searching for **mine** though.. :P

Answer (score 5):

```
function topRise() {
        $(".topRise").animate({
            top: "-900px"
        }, 25000, topSet);
 };
```

It animates the `top` property of any elements with `class="topRise"` to a value of "-900px" over 25000 milliseconds (25 seconds) i.e. it moves them up, then it calls another function called topSet when complete.

Answer (score 4):

jQuery selects the appropriate DOM element, in this case the element with `class` 'topRise':

```
$(."topRise")
```

Calls the jQuery `animate()` function, supplying some CSS properties to be set:

```
{top: "-900px"}
```

the duration of the animation, in milliseconds:

```
25000
```

the callback function which is called on completion

```
topSet
```

putting it all together:

```
function topRise() {
        $(".topRise").animate({
            top: "-900px"
        }, 25000, topSet);
 };
```

More information on [jQuery animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) and
[jQuery selectors](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Answer (score 3):

*what does this function do?*

```
function topRise() {
        $(".topRise").animate({
            top: "-900px"
        }, 25000, topSet);
 };
```

See your function has a jQuery selector and a method named `.animate()` bound on it.

so get it line by line:

1. `$(".topRise")` is the selector which are elements with class name `topRise`.
2. `.animate()` is used to animate css properties of elements.
3. `top:"-900px"` here your element should be animate back to top.
4. `25000` is the time to take to perform animation.
5. `topSet` is a callback function which is getting called when animation ends.

Answer (score 2):

it will set css property top to -900px for tags those having class .topRise by running animation for 25000 millisecond then it will call topSet which is a callback function

Please look here for more info : http://api.jquery.com/animate/